# Where is the respirator implant?

Tags: dex

I've completed a fair number of missions, and I'm reaching a point where most of the remaining quests require the respirator implant to get through a gassed out area.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anyone selling it and I'm down to one remaining non-gas mask mission, the good cop quest.

Where does one receive or buy the respirator implant, in order to walk through poison gas without damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you complete the mission to get a neuroweave implant from warehouse 22 on the Docks, you can then buy the respirator implant from Niles (the doctor).